# Error: cpqCartSummaryContainer RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: error-messages, cpq, vlocity, upgrade

as we're on an older version of Vlocity we had to do a manual upgrade from Spring 23 to Winter 24. I made all the deployment steps based on Salesforce Help but am now running into an error for which I do not have a solution. When trying to configure a Product on an Oppy I receive this error: "Error: cpqCartSummaryContainer RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I would need a solution on how to avoid this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be a winter'24 bug with salesforce, Kindly review [Known Issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXTPl/error-in-industries-cpq-cart-after-upgrading-the-org-to-winter-24) details and click on report button.

Meanwhile you can try below workaround.

- Open the Flexcard cpqConfigureCartItem.
- Create a new version.
- Click    on Quantity.
- On the right side go to properties.
- Under Mask remove #    symbol.
- Activate a new version of flex card

Comment: Thank you for this information. I tried to follow the workaround but receiving a new error when I try to activate the new version saying: Could not deploy. Error msg: No MODULE named markup://c:cfCpqConfigureErrorPanel found : [markup://c:cfCpqConfigureCartItem], Any Idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you try 1. manually activate the errored out cards and enable LWS in the org and then try re-deploying.